# How to Adjust divs and links under each other

Tags: html, css

2 of them should be on the same line and the next div should fall just below them, while both 3 divs centered in the middle of the wrapper. I am targeting a register and login then a search box below both of them
 my html is

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="reglog>
         <a href="#">Register</a>
         <a href="#">Login</a>          
      </div>
      <div id="search">Quick Search</div>
</div> <!--End of wrapper-->.
```

my css is

```
   #wrapper{
            float:right;
            max-width:380px;
            text-align:center             
           }

    #reglog{
            display:inline-block
            }
```

I was hoping that not giving any style to id=search, it will just fall below the reglog block...
Any help on why I cant get this to work?

Thanks
**Michelle**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `display:block;` instead of `inline-block`. Check updated snippet below..

```css
#wrapper{
  float:right;
  max-width:380px;
  text-align:center             
}
#reglog, #search{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="reglog>
         <a href="#">Register</a>
         <a href="#">Login</a>          
      </div>
      <div id="search">Quick Search</div>
</div> <!--End of wrapper-->.
```

Comment: Thanks @Super. almost got there but the first divs will not center. #reglog have a combined width of say 120px, #search have a width of 240px. while #wrapper is aroubd 300px. #reglog will not center horizontally in #wrapper.

Comment: Oh Got it now Super and it works well, I had to include display:inline block for reglog and only display:block for #search. Will do some research why. cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `display:flex;` and specify the flex direction you want using `flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;`

Also you should attach these CSS properties to a `<div></div>` which contain all of your three divs.

You can find all information about this here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/